# MPI Send/Recv error

Tags: c++, mpi

I have written a test program in C++ to make sure I understand how MPI send/recv works (Apparently I don't.) This test runs on 4 processors. The specific case I am interested in, processor 0 sends the array, "send_n" to processor 2, which receives it in the array, "recv_s".  After the inital send, the array is correct (it should be all 5's), but after I do some additional send/recv's, the array somehow changes. What am I doing wrong here?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
# include "mpi.h"
void passBCs(double recv_n[],double recv_e[],double recv_s[],double recv_w[]);
int getNextProcID(int pID, int direction);
int procID,numProcs;
int gridx=2,gridy=2;
int procGridX=2, procGridY=2; 
int main(){
int i,j,k;
int cryptIDs[2]={0,3};
int villusIDs[2]={1,2};

double recv_n[gridx*5],recv_e[gridy*5],recv_s[gridx*5],recv_w[gridy*5];

MPI::Init();
procID=MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_rank();
numProcs=MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_size();
if(procID==0){cout<<"MPI Initialized\n";}


passBCs(recv_n,recv_e,recv_s,recv_w);   
MPI::COMM_WORLD.Barrier();



if(procID==2){
for(i=0;i<10;i++){cout<<"Test Buffer="<<recv_s[i]<<"\n";}}

MPI::Finalize();    

if(procID==0){cout<<"Test Run Exiting Normally\n";}

}   


 void passBCs(double recv_n[],double recv_e[],double recv_s[],double recv_w[]){
int i,j,k,nId,eId,sId,wId,n_rId,e_rId,s_rId,w_rId;
int ntag,etag,stag,wtag;
double send_n[gridx*5],send_e[gridy*5],send_s[gridx*5],send_w[gridy*5];


ntag=0;
etag=1;
stag=2;
wtag=3;

if(procID==0){
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    send_n[i]=5;
    send_s[i]=1;
    send_e[i]=2;
    send_w[i]=3;
}}
else{   for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    send_n[i]=0;
    send_s[i]=0;
    send_e[i]=0;
    send_w[i]=0;
}}


nId=getNextProcID(procID,0);
eId=getNextProcID(procID,1);
sId=getNextProcID(procID,2);
wId=getNextProcID(procID,3);

n_rId=getNextProcID(procID,2);
e_rId=getNextProcID(procID,3);
s_rId=getNextProcID(procID,0);
w_rId=getNextProcID(procID,1);

if(procID==2){cout<<"South Recv ID="<<n_rId<<"\n";}
if(procID==0){cout<<"Proc 0 sending North to "<<nId<<"\n";}

MPI::COMM_WORLD.Send(&send_n[0],20,MPI::DOUBLE,nId,ntag);
MPI::COMM_WORLD.Recv(&recv_s[0],20,MPI::DOUBLE,n_rId,ntag);
if(procID==2){
for(i=0;i<10;i++){cout<<"Test Buffer0="<<recv_s[i]<<"\n";}}

MPI::COMM_WORLD.Send(&send_e[0],20,MPI::DOUBLE,eId,etag);
MPI::COMM_WORLD.Recv(&recv_w[0],20,MPI::DOUBLE,e_rId,etag);
if(procID==2){
for(i=0;i<10;i++){cout<<"Test Buffer1="<<recv_s[i]<<"\n";}}

MPI::COMM_WORLD.Send(&send_s[0],20,MPI::DOUBLE,sId,stag);
MPI::COMM_WORLD.Recv(&recv_n[0],20,MPI::DOUBLE,s_rId,stag);

MPI::COMM_WORLD.Send(&send_w[0],20,MPI::DOUBLE,wId,wtag);
MPI::COMM_WORLD.Recv(&recv_e[0],20,MPI::DOUBLE,w_rId,wtag);

}

int getNextProcID(int pID, int direction){
//Returns the ID number for the processor that is "direction" to the give proc id.
//0=north,1=east,2=south,3=west;
int x_pos,y_pos,nextID; 
x_pos=pID%procGridX;
y_pos=pID/procGridY;
if(direction==0){y_pos++;}
if(direction==1){x_pos++;}
if(direction==2){y_pos--;}
if(direction==3){x_pos--;}
if(x_pos<0){x_pos=procGridX-1;}
if(x_pos>=procGridX){x_pos=0;}
if(y_pos<0){y_pos=procGridY-1;}
if(y_pos>=procGridY){y_pos=0;}
nextID=y_pos*procGridY+x_pos;
return nextID;  
}
```

The output is:

```
MPI Initialized
South Recv ID=0
Proc 0 sending North to 2
Test Buffer0=5
Test Buffer0=5
Test Buffer0=5
Test Buffer0=5
Test Buffer0=5
Test Buffer0=5
Test Buffer0=5
Test Buffer0=5
Test Buffer0=5
Test Buffer0=5
Test Buffer1=0
Test Buffer1=0
Test Buffer1=0
Test Buffer1=0
Test Buffer1=0
Test Buffer1=0
Test Buffer1=0
Test Buffer1=0
Test Buffer1=5
Test Buffer1=5
Test Buffer=0
Test Buffer=0
Test Buffer=0
Test Buffer=0
Test Buffer=0
Test Buffer=0
Test Buffer=0
Test Buffer=0
Test Buffer=5
Test Buffer=5
Test Run Exiting Normally
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error you are observing is caused either by an unfortunate combination of inconsistent edits you made to your file or a misinterpretation of the `count` parameter of `MPI::COMM_WORLD.Send`.
From the docs of [OpenMPI](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_Send.3.php):

> void Comm::Send(const void* buf, int count, const Datatype&
>       datatype, int dest, int tag) const
>
> buf: Initial address of send buffer (choice).
>
> count: Number of elements send (nonnegative integer).
>
> datatype: Datatype of each send buffer element (handle).
>
> dest: Rank of destination (integer).
>
> tag: Message tag (integer).
>
> comm: Communicator (handle).

Note that the count parameter is the number *elements* as defined by the third argument (not some type-independent size measure). Apparently, you originally either had 20 elements in your arrays or you thought that the `count` parameter denotes the size of the send buffer in 4-byte blocks. Anyway, your MPI command refers to 20 elements, for example `MPI::COMM_WORLD.Send(&send_n[0],20,MPI::DOUBLE,nId,ntag);`. Therefore, the `Recv` commands write data that was sent from beyond the end of an array to a location beyond the end of the target array! You were just lucky not to see a segfault (and lucky again because the compiler put your arrays next to each other so you actually saw the effect of writing outside the array). I just compiled your program, replacing  all those `20`s with `10`s and it runs fine (I am not reposting the code because it's just such a simple change).

Output after the change:

```
MPI Initialized
Proc 0 sending North to 2
South Recv ID=0
Test Buffer0=5
Test Buffer0=5
Test Buffer0=5
Test Buffer0=5
Test Buffer0=5
Test Buffer0=5
Test Buffer0=5
Test Buffer0=5
Test Buffer0=5
Test Buffer0=5
Test Buffer1=5
Test Buffer1=5
Test Buffer1=5
Test Buffer1=5
Test Buffer1=5
Test Buffer1=5
Test Buffer1=5
Test Buffer1=5
Test Buffer1=5
Test Buffer1=5
Test Buffer=5
Test Buffer=5
Test Buffer=5
Test Buffer=5
Test Buffer=5
Test Buffer=5
Test Buffer=5
Test Buffer=5
Test Buffer=5
Test Buffer=5
Test Run Exiting Normally
```

To avoid those mistakes in the future, couple the sizes of your arrays with the `count` you pass to the `Send` command, e.g., through some compile time constant or preprocessor macro. Since you are using C++ anyways, why not use `std::vector<double>` instead of double arrays, whose size you can determine at run time before you send them, no matter how they were constructed?